# (empty($_POST['submit'])) not working while I can see there is a value in debugger

Tags: php, post, url-routing

I have a website where I want to prevent that the user gets to a specific page trough the url. So I only want it to make accessible when they pressed on the submit button on the first page.

The problem is that with this code I automatically go to the `index.php?page=home`, while `$_POST` is not empty. If `$_POST` is not empty I want the user to get on the other page.

This is my html:

```
<form action="index.php?page=cart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name = "submit"  value = "submit" />
    <button type="submit" 
            name="action"
            value="details"
            class="btn btn--big btn--big-2 btn--dark">
        your details -> 
    </button>
</form>
```

This the code I use in the controller:

```
public function detail() {
  if(empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    header('Location: index.php?page=home');
    exit();
  }else {

//Rest of code..
}
```

When I look in the debugger, there is a $_POST with the value submit, thus this is why I find it so strange.

Comment: Why not use a submit input?
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">`
Is your hidden field accomplishing anything besides passing 'submit' as a key=>value pair?

Comment: Use `if( strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],'post') !== 0)`  instead of `empty($_POST['submit'])`

Comment: Have you output anything before that? The header won't work if you have.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working when you do what action

Comment: i assume there is a form tag here? you can also use sessions to do this

Comment: yes there is  @tim

Comment: Could you add the form tags, with its action?

Comment: also, maybe try if(!isset($_POST['submit']) --  my usual check

Comment: @TCooper also tried it, doesn't work either..

Comment: @bassxzero doens't work either.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD Then I'm back to my original question, why use a hidden field + button to submit instead of input with type submit?

Comment: @TCooper because I want to have a button with the action - details.

Comment: @GrantC. updated it.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that this function you think is getting called, isn't. Put `header("Content-Type: text/plain"); var_dump($_POST); die;` as first line of the function. What does it tell you?